# Autoloading not working on Amazon Linux (EC2)

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, autoload

I am using an `autoloader` to automatically include all my plugin classes in WordPress. This works fine locally. However, if I put the same code on Amazon EC2 instance, it fails to find the classes. The file paths are correct, I compared the ones on my local installation to the ones on the EC2 instance.

Here is the original code in question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193997/namespaces-in-wordpress-how-do-i-initiate-the-main-class

Comment: can we see the code?

Comment: Yes! I had posted a question. However, I found the issue was with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. I had used '\', which worked fine on Windows and not on Linux. Dumb mistake! Used the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant, and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I have found that same problem, however in my case culprit was the git. Earlier I have created the folder **Abc** on my development machine and pushed it. Later I renamed the folder to **abc** but it was not effectively pushed into the git. I have resolved the problem using following git commands:

`git reset HEAD
git mv Abc tmp
git mv tmp abc
git commit -am 'Case sensitive folder rename fix'
git push`